# How to access Chrome's $0 ($_) from selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

Neither of the below seem to work (Python example):

```
driver.execute_script(r'return $0')
driver.execute_script(r'return window.$0')
```

Comment: Are you running tests on the actual Developer Tools window?

Comment: $0 is a dev tools functionality if what you want to get is the active/focused  element at the moment you need to use `document.activeElement`.

Comment: This won't work and neither it should be needed in your test. These are devtools features and they work when you debug in chrome and they are not javascript functionality which runs on the page. So you first describe what you want to do instead of showing how you are trying to do it

Comment: I usually run DevTools to debug my tests and it would be great to get inter-operability, but I just read that ChromeDriver works as a competing debugger so I guess this won't be possible.